# Sun Grid Engine get history job information

Tags: sungridengine

Is there any way seeing history finished job info in Sun Grid Engine, `qstat -j jobId` can only get job info in qstat list. If such jobId not exists in its current output list, it will output `Following jobs do not exist`. So can i get finished job information?

Answer (score 4):

The `qacct` command allows you to inspect historical job information

Example:

`qacct -o myuser -j -d 7`

Show all jobs by myuser in the last 7 days. The `qacct` command provides important historical information such as runtime and memory used by the job.